# QWebView has glitchy graphics when loading animated gifs

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwebview

Here's a SSCCE:

#### test.pro

```
QT += core gui network webkitwidgets widgets

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = test
INCLUDEPATH += .

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += test.cpp
HEADERS += test.hpp
```

#### test.hpp

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWebView>

class Window : public QMainWindow {
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Window();

private:
  QWebView* m_web;

private slots:
};
```

#### test.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGridLayout>

#include "test.hpp"

Window::Window() :
    QMainWindow() {
  auto* w = new QWidget(this);
  setCentralWidget(w);

  auto* layout = new QGridLayout(centralWidget());
  m_web = new QWebView(this);
  layout->addWidget(m_web, 0, 0, 1, 3);

  m_web->load(QUrl("http://www.hampsterdance.com/classics/originaldance.htm"));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  Window w;
  w.show();

  return a.exec();
}
```

#### Compile instructions:

```
qmake test.pro
make
./test
```

#### Result

[image: Graphical glitch occurring]

#### Questions

My questions are:  Is there a workaround or something to force QWebView to not display these garbled graphics?  Am I doing something wrong in this example?  Is this a known bug/issue?

#### Environment

Tested and reproduced under Linux x64 using g++ 4.8.1 and Qt 5.0.2 and Windows XP using g++ 4.8.1 and Qt 5.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug in Qt](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-31936) which you can fix by updating your version to at least 5.2.

Unfortunately, 5.2 is not quite out yet, so I had to update to 5.2-rc1